# Pulling Specific Row Values based on Another Column

Tags: r

Simple question here -

if I have a dataframe such as:

```
> dat

  typeID ID  modelOption
1      2  1         good
2      2  2          avg
3      2  3          bad
4      2  4   marginCost
5      1  5 year1Premium
6      1  6         good
7      1  7          avg
8      1  8          bad
```

and I wanted to pull **only** the modelOption values based on the typeID. I know I can subset out all rows corresponding with the typeID, but I just want to pull the modelOption values in this case.

Comment: `dat[dat$typeID == 2, "modelOption"]`, for example

Comment: or more explicit: `subset(dat, subset = (typeID == 1), select = "modelOption")`